# pfSense LAN network unable to communicate with remote network on OpenVPN TAP connection

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, route, tap

I set up pfSense to connect to a remote network (`192.168.122.0/24`) that only accepts **tap** connections.

*The connection is being initiated successfully.*

**pfSense (`192.168.1.1/24`)** itself can connect to remote hosts:

```
pfsense# traceroute -n 192.168.122.1
traceroute to 192.168.122.1 (192.168.122.1), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  192.168.122.1  116.968 ms  54.357 ms  52.655 ms
```

**Hosts on the pfSenses' LAN network (e.g. `192.168.1.8/24`)** fail to connect:

```
lan-machine# traceroute -n 192.168.122.1
traceroute to 192.168.122.1 (192.168.122.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1  0.283 ms  0.303 ms  0.379 ms
```

---

**UPDATE:** Running a ping from LAN to a host fails, but **tcpdump** on pfSense shows that the packets are correctly forwarded:

```
lan-machine# ping 192.168.122.1
pfsense# tcpdump -vvi ovpnc4
tcpdump: listening on ovpnc4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
11:54:06.975866 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.1.8 > 192.168.122.1: ICMP echo request, id 23622, seq 106, length 64
```

---

**What is necessary in order to have the interface route correctly?**

(Note that LAN net needs to stay `192.168.1.0/24`)

Comment: OpenVPN? Any logs?

Comment: Hi Frank, the OpenVPN connection is up and running just fine. What else could I provide to help closing in on the issue?